# jsf2 get updated value from bean through javascript

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces

Here is my problem:
I have some table with users `<rich:dataTable>` and table for adding new user `<table>`. Then I'm clicking on `<a4j:commandButton oncomplete="fnIsAdded()">` my form submitted and in `fnIsAdded()` I need to pass value from bean, like  `<a4j:commandButton oncomplete="fnIsAdded(#{bean.somProperty})">`. This is not working, so I need to pass it first to some hidden field `<h:inputHidden value="#{bean.somProperty}">` and when to take it by javascript. My problem now is that the value that is get from javascript (from hidden field) is not refreshed if it's changed in bean. Once it got some value it stays static.

Answer (score 0):

If `#{bean.somProperty}` returns a string which does not represent a boolean or a number in JavaScript syntax, then you need to quote it, otherwise JavaScript will interpret it as a variable name.

```html
<a4j:commandButton ... oncomplete="fnIsAdded('#{bean.somProperty}')" />
```

As to the concrete question, just ajax-render the component.

```html
<a4j:commandButton ... render="hidden" />
<h:inputHidden id="hidden" ... />
```

Comment: `'#{bean.somProperty}'` is not working, it it shows `'#{bean.somProperty}'` as value. But! I found, that `'${bean.somProperty}'` is working with single quote!